# English as default language but comments in another

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I do comments in another language that Visual Studio language is set (english). Nevertheless Visual Studio highlights my comments as wron spelling. Is there any solution to say Visual Studio to recognize my origin language for comments to be not highlited as wrong?

Comment: VS does not spell-check comments.  You surely have an add-in installed that does it, you'll have to disable it.

Comment: @HansPassant the only tool i have installed is resharper